# rails 3.1 asset pipeline: ignore assets from a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets, asset-pipeline

I'm not quite sure what the actual behavior is, so my first question is:
Are assets (e.g. javascripts) from a gem (in my case Spree) always compiled? I don't use Spree's javascripts, and therefore don't want them to be compiled. I don't require them in my `application.js` or any other javascript file, but

```
rake assets:precompile
```

compiles them nonetheless. I just don't want them lying around in my `public/assets` folder.

So I guess my question is, is there a way to disable compiling javascripts from a gem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there is a smart way to achieve your goal using `sprockets`. Maybe some `require_directory` instead of `require_tree`.

But the most direct thing would be to remove theses assets from your assets paths. To achieve this, add this ***at the very end*** of your `application.rb` file (doesn't work in an initializer):

```
class Engine < Rails::Engine
   initializer "remove assets directories from pipeline" do |app|
     app.config.assets.paths = app.config.assets.paths - app.config.assets.paths.grep(/nice_regexp_here_to_match_the_dir_where_the_unwanted_files_live/)
   end
end
```

---

Just tried a hack: put the code in an `initializer` but require it at the end of your `application.rb`:

```
require "config/initializers/your_file'
```

I prefer very specific code to be visible this way.

Comment: In Rails 4.0.0 it looks like the initializer is ignored. Try:

    class Engine < Rails::Engine
       config.assets.paths = ...
    end

Answer (score 3):

## Rails 4.X

It didn't work on Rails 4.X, a possible (dirty) workaround is:

```
require 'sprockets/railtie'

Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

module Sprockets
  module Paths
    SKIP_GEMS = ["rails-assets-jquery", "rails-assets-bootstrap"]

    def append_path_with_rails_assets(path)
      append_path_without_rails_assets(path) unless SKIP_GEMS.any? { |gem| path.to_s.start_with?(Gem.loaded_specs[gem].full_gem_path) }
    end

    alias_method_chain :append_path, :rails_assets
  end
end
```

## Update for Rails 5.X

`alias_method_chain` is deprecated since Rails 5.X. Here is an updated version using `prepend`, and overriding the `Sprockets::Environment` module instead of `Sprockets::Paths`.

```
module SprocketsPathsOverride
  SKIP_GEMS = ["rails-assets-jquery", "rails-assets-bootstrap"]

  def append_path(path)
    should_skip = SKIP_GEMS.any? do |gem|
      path.to_s.start_with?(Gem.loaded_specs[gem].full_gem_path)
    end
    super(path) unless should_skip
  end
end

Sprockets::Environment.prepend(SprocketsPathsOverride)
```

Comment: putting this into config/initializers/duplicate_assets.rb worked fine for me too. Can be tested with rails runner "puts Rails.application.assets.find_asset('jquery.js').to_a.map(&:pathname)"