# How to exclude a gem when running assert precompile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I deploy an app using Capistrano, it get deployed successfully, however, I have added a gem that will break the deployment when assets precompile task get executed.

How can I exclude specific gem when running `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` ?

Comment: Which gem is breaking your deployment ? Can you show me the log ?

Comment: The log indicates that higher ruby version is needed, however, I do not want to change the ruby version, and the gem works fine, it has no assets to precompile.. `/var/www/preprod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/facebook-ruby-business-sdk-46a6340acc63/lib/facebook_ads/crash_logger.rb:72:in `block in is_facebook_error': undefined method `match?' for #<String:0x0055dcea249538> (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  match`

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163264/rails-3-1-asset-pipeline-ignore-assets-from-a-gem) post